# Maven looks for jar that isn't present in the repository

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, artifactory, artifacts

I have a repository set up on Artifactory for my Maven projects. I have declared this repo in the `<repositories>` tag of my settings.xml for one of the projects, I have created a dependency on some other prooject (Say projectA) in my POM for a snapshot version. For this projectA, there is only POM artifact on the Artifactory and not a jar. Still when I compile my POM, Maven tries to download the jar for this project and fails saying it couldn't find it.

I shall paste the exact POM, error, settings.xml and repo view soon. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: what's the type of the artifact you are depending on? if it is of type JAR (which is default) , of course Maven will try to download it.

Comment: In my packaging field I have not definied anything. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: That means the dependency is actually or type jar right? If you declared a dependency to a jar artifact, what is the problem for Maven trying to download it?

Comment: There is not enough information to solve this issue. If the jar you are trying to download is your code, at some point you will need to deploy it on artifactory. If it is looking for a public artefact on your artifactory perhaps you have a configuration problem in your settings.xml and your maven installation do not retrieve artefact from maven repo central.

Comment: @AdrianShum If I understand correctly, <packaging> field in the POM says what form you want your POM's project to be packaged in and not what forms of artifacts your dependencies are.

Comment: @drgn I'm not trying to download a jar. I'm just trying to download whatever format of artifact the dependency is. Its not a public artifact. Its one of my internal projects whose final POM is on the Artifactory and that is what I want to be downloaded.

Comment: Assume you have a `foo` lib, for which in its POM, it is of packaging `jar` (the default).  Now you have a `bar` project which depends on `foo`, then of course when building `bar`, Maven will try to find `foo` from local and remote repo, and treating it as a `jar` packaging.  So what's the problem that Maven is trying to download `foo-x.y.z.jar` from your remote repo?

Comment: Sorry I should've been clearer. In my case, foo's POM packaging type is POM not a jar.

Comment: Then check your local repo, I suspect you have outdated `foo-SNAPSHOT` POM file that have no packaging defined.  When Maven is building `bar`, it found `foo-SNAPSHOT` POM from your local repo for which it has no packaging so Maven may try to download it.  Still, the best way is to make up a simple project that can simulate this and post the files + errors out

Comment: As I understand you are trying to have a pom packaging as a dependency. Then drorb's answer is valid. You have to specify the type if it is not a jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to have a dependency of pom type, you need to explicitly declare it. For example:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

If type is not specified, Maven would use the default value which is jar.

Edit from OP: Just a caution, I use IntelliJ and even though I had the settings right in place, it was using some old (probably cached) settings.xml. I ran from commandline and it picked up the right one.

Comment: I agree with that, when it comes to interact with Maven to build your final package, I always prefer the command-line instead of any IDE - that way you have more guarantees that the build will work on any other machine (mainly the machine where the CI runs).